# get highlighted text using jquery .select()?

Tags: jquery

I was trying example code found here http://api.jquery.com/select/

```
$(":input").select( function () { 
      $("div").text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(1000); 
    });
```

Now my question is instead of printing "Something was selected" , can I get exact selected text?

I want jquery .select() specific answers . I got other solution from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KgtW5/3/)

Comment: did you solved your issue?I have posted an answer that will help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.select()` has nothing to do with retrieving the actual selected text. Select is just like `.click()`: an easy, shorthand way way to bind a handler function to the select event.

It says right in [the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/select/):

> The method for retrieving the current selected text differs from one browser to another. A number of jQuery plug-ins offer cross-platform solutions.

So you bind with `element.select(...)` (or better still, `element.on("select", ...)`), and then you use one of the many cross-platform solutions to retrieve the selection. This is the basic idea: http://jsfiddle.net/NjW5a/3/

Answer (score 5):

.Select()  seems like just an event that will fire on selection of that specific element. However, to get the text you will need to use javascript's *window.getSelection()* function.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BCv4Y/3/

```
    $(":input").select( function () { // on selection, show what's selected
        $("div").text(window.getSelection()).show().fadeOut(1000); 
     }

});
```

​

Perhaps, It will be great if new version of jquery comes with something like *$(this).selectedVal()*. Hope that helps

Comment: Ithcy is right. IE doesn't support that window.getSelection() function, thus we will have to a cross-platform solution like the *getSelected* function he mentioned in the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/NjW5a/3/

(Source: Ithcy ^^ )

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
window.onmouseup = mouseup;
function mouseup() {
 getSelText();
 }
</script>
   <script  type="text/javascript">
function getSelText() {
var txt = '';
if (window.getSelection) {
    alert (window.getSelection());
} else if (document.getSelection) {
   alert (document.getSelection());
   } else if (document.selection) {
     alert( document.selection.createRange().text);

 } else return;

 }
</script>
```

Comment: OP said: *"I want jquery .select() specific answers."* This doesn't seem to use `.select()` and it's therefore not really useful as an answer on this specific question.