# JQuery .select after setting value using .val

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have two Radtextboxes (telerik) in two tabstrips inside my html. I want to set the value of each based on the change made by user on other. I have achived using following code:

```js
function OnUsernameChanged() {
  $('#txtUserNameTab1').focus(function (e) {
    $(this).select();
  });
  $('#txtUserNameTab2').focus(function (e) {
    $(this).select();
  });
  $('#txtUserNameTab1').bind('keypress blur keyup', function (e) {
    var userNameValue = $(this).val();
    $('#txtUserNameTab2').val($(this).val());

  });
  $('#txtUserNameTab2').bind('keypress blur keyup', function (e) {
    var userNameValue = $(this).val();
    $('#txtUserNameTab1').val($(this).val());
  });
}
```

Its all working fine with updating the value of second textbox when first's value is changed and vice versa. But the issue is with select, when focussed on any of the textbox, it always does a select all on that textbox, but the value gets changed to initial value of the textbox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211964/get-highlighted-text-using-jquery-select are you trying to get the selected value?

Comment: No, my intention is to make the full text in the textbox selected so that user can directly write over it.

Comment: this seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/U4YkM/

Comment: It worked fine when i changed the textboxes to simple input textbox from telerik radtextbox...

Comment: I don't understand the effect you're attempting to achieve.  The full-text is selected in the textbox when I tab into it.  This is the default behavior that I observe without any JavaScript attached to my RadTextboxes

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle that works the way you wanted with textbox controls.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZeEXp/1/

JS:

```
        $('#txtUserNameTab1,#txtUserNameTab2').mouseup(function() {
            $(this).select();
        });

        $('#txtUserNameTab1').bind('keyup', function (e) {
            var userNameValue = $(this).val();
            $('#txtUserNameTab2').val($(this).val());
        });

        $('#txtUserNameTab2').bind('keyup', function (e) {
            var userNameValue = $(this).val();
            $('#txtUserNameTab1').val($(this).val());
        });
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="txtUserNameTab1">asdfasdfa</textarea>
<textarea id="txtUserNameTab2">563gh45</textarea>
```