# jQuery get value of Highlighted characters in input field without using plugin

Tags: jquery

I know that jQuery has `.select();` method , the question is can I get the value of this selection ?!

http://api.jquery.com/select/

Simply i need to get the value of Highlighted characters inside text or input box.

Without using any plugins.

Comment: possible duplicate question.  See this question/answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)

Comment: possible duplicate of [get highlighted text using jquery .select()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211964/get-highlighted-text-using-jquery-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" />
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').select(function() {
        alert(window.getSelection());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .selectionStart and .selectionEnd.  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/225B8/

```
<input type="text" name="foobar" id="foobar" /><button type="button">Show Value</button>

$("button").click(function() {
    var selected = getSelect($("#foobar"));
    alert('highlighted text: ' + selected);
});

function getSelect($el) { 
    var fullvalue = $el.val(),
        el = $el.get(0);

    return $el.val().substring(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
}
```