# Get highlighted input value

Tags: html, input, angular2-forms

is there a way to get an input value and retrieve if the value is highlighted? 
I've a simple input:

```
 <input type="text" id="myId" [(ngModel)]="myModel" (keypress)="myNumberInput($event)" min=0 max=99999/>
```

I'd should know throw event if the value in the input is highlighted. For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdAs3.jpg)

Is it possible to get this information in event?
Thanks

PS. I'm developing in Angular 2 so I need to do this without using jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of Highlighted characters in input field without using plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526578/jquery-get-value-of-highlighted-characters-in-input-field-without-using-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me :

```
<input type="text" id="myId" [(ngModel)]="myModel"  (select)="myNumberInput($event)" min=0 max=99999/>
```