# Jquery: catch text selection inside a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a href="http://somthing/1234567890" target="_blank">
    <span class="cls_ani">(123) 456-7890</span>
</a>
```

Using Jquery, how can I catch text selection inside a span and update its text to be unformatted:

```
<span class="cls_ani">1234567890</span>
```

I'am also trying to revert that when the span is not selected anymore.

Using this selector: $(".cls_ani")

Note: the click on the ani is a link and should still take to:

```
http://somthing/1234567890
```

Comment: $(".cls_ani").text();

Comment: Do you just want to display what is inside the span tag or highlight everything inside it?

Comment: @Sudharsan I think he means text *selection*, not the inner text

Comment: OP - what happens if I select some text from inside the span and some text from outside it. What would your expected output be then? Because you might be looking for just [window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection) combined with a simple [.mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) event

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211964/get-highlighted-text-using-jquery-select

Comment: I have the same question. I'll top the OP's question with does a HTML tag have the functionality by default?

Comment: Read this http://mark.koli.ch/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text

Comment: I am trying to remove the formatting from the ANI's that were selected, for example if the above span got selected i wan't to change its text to be 1234567890 (to make it easy to the user to copy this unformatted ANI and use it somewhere else). I am also trying to revert the ANI's to the original values when they are not selected anymore.

Comment: I have updated the post description

Comment: @imbondbaby I have updated the post description

Comment: @RGraham I have updated the post description

Answer (score 1):

This will work for what you want (get the selected text)

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Of course maybe you want to check if the selected text is part of the span, in this case, the window.getSelection does not provide that information. but you can do something like this

```
$(".cls_ani").text().indexOf(text) != -1
```

Comment: I like this idea, you should probably show the OP how `getSelectionText` can be passed into their existing jQuery `.select` function